# python how to run script in folder

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is my python path:

```
PYTHONPATH = D:\PythonPath
```

in the `PythonPath` folder I have `MyTests` folder that has a `Script.py`

in the `PyThonPath` folder I have `ScrapyingProject` folder

inside the `Script.py` I do this:

```
from ScrapyingProject.ScrapyingProject.spiders.XXXSpider import XXXSpider
```

I got this exception:

```
ImportError: No module named ScrapyingProjectScrapyingProject.spiders.XXXSpider
```

#### Edit:

the XXXSpider is in this location:

```
D:\PythonPath\ScrapyingProject2\ScrapyingProject2\spiders.py
```

Comment: Either put the file in the same directory or add the path to the file to your class-path

Comment: i assume `spiders` is a `spider.py` file. Move the file or, wouldn't an implementetion of `if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()` help out here?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this to read more about Python modules and packages: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Turn your python-script-containing folder into a python package by adding `__init__.py` file to it. So, in your case, the directory structure should resemble this:

```
PYTHONPATH
- ScrapyingProject
   - __init__.py
   - script.py
```

Now, in this scheme, `ScrappyProject` becomes your python-package. Any `.py` file inside the folder becomes a python module. You can import a python module by dot-expanded python path starting `PYTHONPATH`. Something like,

`from ScrapyingProject.script import XXXSpider`

Same logic can be extended by nesting multiple packages inside each other. A nested package, for example looks like

```
PYTHONPATH
- ScrapyingProject2
   - __init__.py
   - ScrapyingProject2
       - __init__.py
       - script.py
```

Now, a package-nested script.py can be imported as

```
from ScrapyingProject2.ScrapyingProject2 import script
```

Or even

```
from ScrapyingProject2.ScrapyingProject2.script import XXXSpider
```

(Assuming you have defined `class XXXSpider` inside `script.py`)

Answer (score 0):

For one you say that the directory is `D:\PythonPath\ScrapyingProject2\ScrapyingProject2\spiders.py` but you import from `ScrapyingProject.ScrapyingProject` (without the 2s).
If I understand you correctly, the wanted import should look something like this:

```
from ScrapyingProject2.ScrapyingProject2.spiders import XXXSpider
```

assuming the class XXXSpider is in the module spiders.py.
Remember to put `__init__.py` files in the folders you want to import from (turning them into 'packages'). This should include all folders from the PYTHONPATH to the one containing the *.py-files. See [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) from more details on packages.